# Help with ratio and frequency

Tags: actionscript, modulo

I have the following:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Ratio extends MovieClip {
    private var counter:Number;
    private var frequency:Number;
    private var ratio:String;
    private var max:Number;

    public function Ratio() {
        ratio ="2/8";   
        var arr = ratio.split("/");

        max = arr[1];
        frequency = arr[0];
        counter = 0;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
    }

        private function loop(e:Event):void {
            trace(counter + ": " + (counter < frequency));
            counter++;

            if (counter == max) {
                counter = 0;
            }
        }

        public function destroy():void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs something like:

```
0: true
1: true
2: false
3: false
0: true
1: true
2: false
3: false
```

But what I would actually like is:

```
0: true
1: false
2: true
3: false
0: true
1: false
2: true
3: false
```

i.e. more even dispersion (alternation)...is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have missed the point here, but this should give the desired output:

```
private function loop(e:Event):void {
    trace(counter + ": " + !Boolean(counter % 2));
    counter++;
    if (counter == max)  counter = 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Although it's getting a little heavy-handed, the following creates an alternating dispersion where it is exactly possible.  Everything else runs in a straight sequence.  I'm no mathematician though, and I feel that it could be done better.  For example this will treat 3/9 as `1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0`, whereas a 'nicer' distribution might be `0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0`

```
var ratio:String = "3/5"; 

var counter:int = 0;
var arr = ratio.split("/");
var frequency:int = arr[0];
var max:int = arr[1];

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);

function loop(e:Event):void {
    if((max+1) / frequency == 2 || max / frequency == 2) {
        trace(counter + ": " + !Boolean(counter % 2));
    } else if((max-1) / frequency == 2) {
        trace(counter + ": " + Boolean(counter % 2));
    } else {
        trace(counter < frequency);
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter == max) removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
}
```

Comment: *sort of*... say if my ratio is 3/5 then I would like it to be true-false-true-false-true...or if it's 1/5 I would like true-false-false-false-false...is that even possible??

Comment: So you want the ratio of true/false to be as evenly distributed as possible?  What would be the expected output of 4/5?

Comment: Like say if it were 1/5, or 4/5 you get true-false-false-false-false or false-false-false-false-true...but for 2/5 or 3/5 you get the alternate...I suspect this sounds flakey but I would just like to keep things not "clumpy"

Comment: @redconservatory - Updated. I don't particularly like it though.